# A template function for reading std::vector<T> from a stream

Tags: c++

I have a template ReadVector function that reads std::vector from a stream:

```
    template <class Stream, typename T>
    inline void ReadVector(Stream & s, std::vector<T> & items)
    {
        s.Read(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(items.data()), items.size() * sizeof(T));
    }
```

with the specialization for boolean vector:

```
    template <class Stream>
    void ReadVector(Stream & s, std::vector<bool> & x)
    {
    ...
    }
```

the code above compiles, but I'd like to make the first function called only if T is an arithmetic type, so the condition should be like this:

```
std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !std::is_same(T, bool)::value
```

but I cannot figure out what is the syntax.

Also I'd like to have yet another specialization of ReadVector if T is not bool and is not arithmetic.

My first idea was something like this:

```
    template <class Stream, typename T>
    void ReadVector(Stream & s, std::vector<T> & items);

    template <class Stream, typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value, void>::type ReadVector(Stream & s, std::vector<T> & items)
    {
    ...
    }
```

but this results in ambiguous call to overloaded function.

Comment: As is, you got two conflict declarations of the same function template: get rid of the first one (or constrain it to the opposite condition if you actually want to keep it).

Comment: @ DietmarKühl, yes, you are right!

Comment: There are many potential problems with that code. In many cases, the behavior is undefined or not portable and the representation might vary depending on compiler options too. **Using a textual format like JSON is preferable as it is more maintainable** and easier to debug and manually fix corrupted data. If data size is important, you can compress the data as it is the case for modern Office file format like DOCX.

Comment: When you pass `vector<int>`, after template parameter substitution, both function are in the overload resolution set and because they are "nearly" identical to each other, this cause the ambiguity.

Comment: @Phil1970 I read and write the file locally on a device, so I can use vector<T>::data().

Comment: @HanXIAO correct.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky You are assuming that you will always write abd read from a specific device and that the data won’t change. At least, if you do so, you should use type that have fixed width. int could be 32 or 64 bit in most current systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out!

```
    template <class Stream, typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value, void>::type ReadVector(Stream & s, std::vector<T> & v)
    {
        s.Read(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(v.data()), v.size() * sizeof(T));
    }

    template <class Stream, typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, void>::type ReadVector(Stream & s, std::vector<T> & v)
    {
        for (auto & elem : v)
        {
            Read(s, elem);
        }
    }

    template <class Stream>
    void ReadVector(Stream & s, std::vector<bool> & x)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: While it might work for some types, this is very fragile. If you want to port on another platform or even just changes compiler options, it won't works properly anymore. It is also very sensitive to changes made to your class. A simple thing like reordering members will break the code.

Comment: @Phil1970 could you please point out why this is fragile and how can compiler options can break it?

Comment: For example, if T is a class and you modify compiler options, the size of T could change if you are not careful. And in the life of an application, you might add some fields to T.... so binary streams are very fragile.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is wrong!

Why not just use the vector constructor?

```
std::vector<int>  v(std::istream_iterator<int>(stream), std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

Don't need a function when it can be done in the vector initializer.

If you want to do something fancy (like read raw data from the stream) you just define a class for reading that specific type of data.

```
struct RawDataToInt
{
     int  value;
     operator int() {return value;}
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, RawDataToInt& v)
     {
         return str.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v.value), sizeof(int));
     }
};
....
std::vector<int>  v(std::istream_iterator<RawDataToInt>(stream), std::istream_iterator<RawDataToInt>());
```

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Does not change anything. Just define the appropriate conversion from RAW to internal type.

Comment: it is a good alternative. Probably I did not understand std::stream enough, but I am worrying a bit about the fact that std::stream is always buffered, in some certain cases I need an implementation of a stream that calls ::ReadFile directly on Win32 platform and I need to call ::FlushFileBuffers with the output stream.